# What are the pros/cons of Eigen::Ref<> vs. std::reference_wrapper<>?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

It appears that `Eigen::Ref<>`, introduced in Eigen 3.2, and `std::reference_wrapper<>` introduced in C++11 accomplish very similar goals.

Obviously, the `Eigen::Ref<>` does not introduce a C++11 dependency, as std::reference_wrapper<> does, but what else should be considered?  (For me, C++11 dependency is not a concern.)

Here are the references: (so meta, LOL):

- [Eigen::Ref<>](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Ref.html)
- [std::reference_wrapper<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do not cover same usage. std::reference_wrapper is typically used to store references to objects of type T into containers (instead of using pointers). Eigen::Ref can wrap any Eigen's dense object that are similar to T or allocate its own memory to evaluate expressions that cannot be referenced. It is typically used as the argument types of non template functions or to unify Map, Matrix, and sub-matrices.

Comment: I found some more detail on this in the section titled: "How to write generic, but non-templated function?" here:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html